# how to move fingerprint template to oracle database

Tags: oracle, blob, fingerprint

i am working with digital persona u are u 4500 and oracle database, i got the problem to store fingerprint template to database, here part of my code

```
string sqlInsert = "insert into mytable(ID,FINGERPRINT)";
       sqlInsert += "values (:i_ID,:i_FINGERPRINT)";

OracleParameter iID = new OracleParameter();
        iID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        iID.Value = textBox1.Text;
        iID.ParameterName = "i_ID";

OracleParameter iFINGERPRINT = new OracleParameter();
        iFINGERPRINT.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
        iFINGERPRINT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        iFINGERPRINT.Value = Data.Templates[5];
        iFINGERPRINT.ParameterName = "i_FINGERPRINT";

cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(iID);
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(iFINGERPRINT);
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

note : Data.Templates[5] is a fingerprint template format

i got error "invalid parameter binding"
what does it mean?
could somebody help me? what should i do?
thanks in advance

Comment: I belive it means that you want to bind wrong type of data to  iFINGERPRINT.Value param. check if Data.Templates[5] is binary?

Answer (score 0):

```
                   string path="C:\\Fingerprintimage.bmp";
                    FileStream fls;
                    fls = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    byte[]  blob = new byte[fls.Length];
                    fls.Read(blob, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fls.Length));
                    fls.Close();
                    string q="";
                    q = "insert into mytable(ID,FINGERPRINT) values(" + 1 + ", :BlobParameter)";
                    OracleParameter blobParameter = new OracleParameter();
                    blobParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
                    blobParameter.ParameterName = "BlobParameter";
                    blobParameter.Value = blob;
                    cmd = new OracleCommand(q, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```