# How to save and retrieve fingerprint template to and from MySql using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010, fingerprint

I'm very new to this fingerprint thing on vb.net and mysql. I just started trying to use the digitalpersona u.are.u 4500 and I don't know how to save template to Mysql database. I also want to retrieve the data from Mysql. Here is the code. Thank you! `

```
Private Enroller As DPFP.Processing.Enrollment

Protected Overrides Sub Init()
    MyBase.Init()
    MyBase.Text = "Fingerprint Enrollment"
    Enroller = New DPFP.Processing.Enrollment()     ' Create an enrollment.
    UpdateStatus()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Process(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
    MyBase.Process(Sample)

    ' Process the sample and create a feature set for the enrollment purpose.
    Dim features As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment)

    ' Check quality of the sample and add to enroller if it's good
    If (Not features Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            MakeReport("The fingerprint feature set was created.")
            Enroller.AddFeatures(features)        ' Add feature set to template.
        Finally
            UpdateStatus()

            ' Check if template has been created.
            Select Case Enroller.TemplateStatus
                Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Ready    ' Report success and stop capturing
                    RaiseEvent OnTemplate(Enroller.Template)
                    SetPrompt("Click Close, and then click Fingerprint Verification.")
                    StopCapture()

                Case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Failed   ' Report failure and restart capturing
                    Enroller.Clear()
                    StopCapture()
                    RaiseEvent OnTemplate(Nothing)
                    StartCapture()

            End Select
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub UpdateStatus()
    ' Show number of samples needed.
    SetStatus(String.Format("Fingerprint samples needed: {0}", Enroller.FeaturesNeeded))
End Sub

Private Sub EnrollmentForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'bioenrollment
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1266, 630)
    Me.Name = "bioenrollment"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789426/how-to-move-fingerprint-template-to-oracle-database

Comment: That's oracle bro. I'm using vb.net. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same concept.  If the template is a string you insert as you would any string.  Oracle is a database.  VB.NET is a language.  And it looks like they are using a .NET language in the question.

Comment: problem is I dont know how to do that. sorry, newbie here.

Comment: I voted to close because the question is too broad.  There are many, many questions and answers on SO on how to insert data into a MySQL database.  Don't take it wrong.  I think you should just understand that if your only question is how to insert data into a MySQL database, there are multiple ways to do so explained across many SO questions.  Search for Insert data into a MySQL database.  If that does not answer, you will be able to better articulate a more exact question.

Answer (score 0):

The DigitalPersona Fingerprint Reader will allow you to serialize the fingerprint to an XML file......you just store this in the database as a Varchar(MAX).

Comment: problem is I dont know how to do that. sorry, newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for insert

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim fingerprintData As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Template.Serialize(fingerprintData)
    fingerprintData.Position = 0
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fingerprintData)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(CType(fingerprintData.Length, Int32))

    Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    Dim SQLcommand As SQLiteCommand
    SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "data source=C:\Users\mypc\Documents\MatrixDbase.s3db"
    SQLconnect.Open()
    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Longin (id, Fname, Lname, Pic) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', @Pic)"

    SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", bytes)
    'Runs Query
    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SQLcommand.Dispose()
    SQLconnect.Close()

End Sub
```